# Select2: Trim entered text and if empty - prevent sending Ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, trim, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 with Ajax to load remote data (suggestions).

Everything works fine, but there is one problem: when a user enters only spaces (by pressing the spacebar) - Ajax request is being sent.

How can I prevent this? Also, I would like to trim terms before being sent.

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  placeholder: "Select... ",
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  ajax: {
    url: "/my-site/tags",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: params.term
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: data
        };
    },
    cache: true
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I have already tried something like this:

```
        data: function (params) {
            if (params.term.trim().length  < 2) {
                return;
            }
            return {
                q: $.trim(params.term)
            };
        },
```

and the GET (Ajax) request is still sent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `data` function to check the length of the search `term` (after trim), and return if the length < 3:

```
data: function (params) {
  if (params.term.trim().length  < 3) {
    throw false;
  }
  return {
    q: params.term.trim()
  };
},
```

I was trying to get the value of `minimumInputLength` from inside the `data` function but couldn't, so you should use have this number written twice.

### update

The only way I was able to stop the request was to `throw` exception inside the the `data` function. I know it's probably not a good option, but it works.

And I also found an open ticket regarding this issue: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1637
So I guess there is no such option (yet).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Unfortunately, this is just one more flaw of Select2. But, before checking your answer as correct - I'll wait a bit, in case if someone else has to say something about this.

Comment: sure :) no problem. I truly hope someone has a better solution (since `throw` is not a good solution imho).

Answer (score 2):

You can just rewrite the `transport` option, return `null` while validation failed, otherwise return the [original function code](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/0de98d99993db0d8b0da6ad01836a120060cb8fe/src/js/select2/data/ajax.js)

It works for me.

```js
{
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: params.term
        };
    },
    transport: function (params, success, failure) {
        if(params.data.q.trim().length < 3) {
            return null;
        }
        //the original function code:
        var $request = $.ajax(params);

        $request.then(success);
        $request.fail(failure);

        return $request;
    },
}
```

Comment: only thing that worked for me

Answer (score -1):

you have to override the transport method by your own function and do anything you want with the parameters then decide to handle the request by XHR OR $.ajax or axios

Comment: because even if we return null or false from data function it doesn't stop the request